# How to run site with vue build file and wordpress in same domain

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, pm2

I have a site hosted with domain [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com) in vue (runs in  pm2).  I need to run my blog page in wordpress. ([www.xxx.com/blog](http://www.xxx.com/blog)).
ie [www.xxx.com/blog](http://www.xxx.com/blog) need to redirect in wordpress page and all other urls with domain [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com) to vue project. Is there any option to do this ?

Comment: apache serve? nginx as reverse proxy?

Comment: @Ifaruki apache+pm2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an `.htaccess` (or the equivalent for other servers) and simple redirect this specific url.

Might look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Wordpress
RewriteRule ^blog$ /path/to/wordpress/index.php [L]

# Vue
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```